# SipSession and HttpSession

Tags: servlets, sip-servlet

How can I associate a `SipSession` with an `HttpSession` in a converged application?

I know that having a `HttpSession` you can create a `SipApplicationSession`, but supposing that I have a web page that is also contacting the SIP server (let's say through web sockets) how can I get the corresponding `HttpSession` of the `SipSession`.

My idea will be to have a `HttpSession` registry, add JSESSIONID as an extra header for SIP messages and then get the corresponding `HttpSession`. is there a better way?

I need this so that user authenticated in the web application to be automatically authenticated on the SIP server too without any additional password challenge (automated or not).

Comment: have you try to get session from request object.

Comment: if you get the session from the request object you will get the HttpSession from the HttpSerletRequest and SipSession from the SipServletRequest. I need the HttpSession from the SipServletRequest. And I guess it needs to be associated somehow.

Comment: just try this ThreadLocal<HttpSession> threadLocalHttpSession = new ThreadLocal<HttpSession>(); and get by this HttpSession httpSession = threadLocalHttpSession.get();.